# add fields to model from another one related with OneToOneField or ForeignKey relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, one-to-one

i am new to django and i am using the 1.11 version 
i have several models some related with foreign keys and some with oneToOne relation.
for instance the user and profile models, i would like to add in the profile form fields from the user form
how?
For the oneToOne, I have the an admin model with a oneToOne field related to the user model. but not just admin, i have several types of user (admin, writer, commetator, ...) each in a different model and when creating one type i also create its related user, so when i access the writer form in admin i create an admin but i also want to have user's model field so that i create both from the writer's form
in AdminAdmin ie: the admin model i would like to add the user's fields in the form showing in the admin template

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User, Admin


class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class AdminAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Admin
    list_display = ['getUsername']
    inlines = [UserInline]

    def getUsername(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    getUsername.short_description = "Nom d'utilisateur"

admin.site.register(Admin, AdminAdmin)
```

this code generates the error ": (admin.E202) 'common.User' has no ForeignKey to 'common.Admin'."

Answer (score 0):

With this setup:

```
Class A(models.Model):
    # ...
    nameField = models.CharField(max_length=100, ...)
    # ...
    pass

Class B(models.Model)
    # ...
    fk = models.ForeignKey(A)
    # ...

Class C(models.Model):
    # ...
    oto = models.OneToOneKeyField(A)
```

You cann access a realted model's field with the `ForeignKey` + `__` + `FieldName`. E.g. you can access the model A's name field from related models with:

**B**

`'fk__name'`

**C**

`'oto__name'`

Comment: thank you for your answer but it did not work i got the error "Unknown field(s) (user__username) specified for Profile. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ProfileAdmin."

Comment: Some more information might be useful to help you. 1) Where did you put that code? 2) Where do you need related fields? (Admin or your own View). 3) For which class do you need those related models? (`models.Model`, `admin.ModelAdmin`, `forms.ModelForm`?)

Comment: please checkout the post

Comment: Then I'd suggest to implement an admin-inline for each foreign key your require a field of. Have a look at the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline)

Comment: i saw that and tried it but it does work for me, following that example i want to have an AuthorInline for BookAdmin

Comment: What exactly does not suit you with inlines? Please be a bit more talkative about your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152489/discussion-between-leila-and-max-m).