# Django 1.11 admin form add search box to oneToOne field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-1.11

I have a user, admin and employee models, both employee and admin are related to the user model with a oneToOne field what i would like to do is in the admin form i have one field "user"
instead of having a drop down field with all users i would like to have a search box so that when i search for a specific user i find him and choose him to be an admin.
how?
i also tried to add user's fields to admin's form but i couldn't
i tried the inline thing, the parent_link in the admin's model... but i couldn't find a solution
Now i would like to minimise the search through the long users list by adding a search box to the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this type of problem using [django-ajax-selects](http://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install.html) package. Hope this will help you.

**app/admin.py:**

```
from ajax_select import register, LookupChannel

@register('users')
class UsersLookup(LookupChannel):

    model = User

    def get_query(self, q, request):
          return self.model.objects.filter(username__icontains=q)

class EmployeeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = AutoCompleteSelectField('users', required=False, 
                                  help_text=None)

    class Meta:
         model = Employee
         fields = '__all__'
```

**settings.py**

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'users'  : {'model': 'auth.user', 'search_field': 'username'},
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer but m getting "Reverse for 'ajax_lookup' not found. 'ajax_lookup' is not a valid view function or pattern name."????

Comment: You have to add '
    url(r'^ajax_select/', include(ajax_select_urls)),' in your urls.py  check the installation page.  :)

Comment: if you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786983/add-fields-to-model-from-another-one-related-with-onetoonefield-or-foreignkey-re

Answer (score 0):

Use django's [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields). With that you can declare a foreign key object searchable.

Comment: how to make the search by username instead of the id?